# Struts2 JQuery DatePicker: enable only particular dates in calendar

Tags: jquery, struts2, datepicker, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I need to enable only particular dates in a calendar, disabling all the other dates.

I tried with `onCompleteTopics` and `onBeforeShowDayTopics` using Struts2-jQuery DatePicker without success.

With raw jQuery I am able to do it [as shown in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/4/)

I need the same functionality using Struts2-jQuery DatePicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable only a particular set of dates (Close Event in [the showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)) in Struts2-jQuery DatePicker, you need to use the [`onBeforeShowDayTopics`](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag#Topics) :

```
<script>
    var availableDates = ["8-12-2014","25-12-2014","26-12-2014"];

    $(function(){           
        $.subscribe('beforeDatepickerShow', function(event, data) {
            var date = event.originalEvent.date;
            var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" 
                    + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" 
                    + date.getFullYear();
            if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
                event.originalEvent.returnValue = [true, "","Available"];
            } else{
                event.originalEvent.returnValue = [false,"","unAvailable"];
            }
    });
<script>
<sj:datepicker onBeforeShowDayTopics = "beforeDatepickerShow" 
                                name = "myDate" 
                               label = "With Close Event" />
```

Note: [this feature was buggy in the past](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=718), so be sure you are not using an old version of the plugin.

Since 3.3.0 it is fixed and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for giving quick solution which plugin i need to use 3.3.0 and above whether struts2 plugin or struts2 jquery plugin.I'm using <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency> but still not working with your code

Comment: yup thankx andrea struts2 jquery plugin updated to 3.3.1 now its working.You saved my time.Once again a big thanks to solve my both problem.

Comment: You're welcome. You need to use *at least* struts2-jquery-plugin 3.3.0. BTW, you should consider upgrading to Struts2 2.3.16.3, and then to struts2-jquery-plugin 3.7.1, to take advantage of all the security patches, bugfixes and performance improvement.

Comment: Hey andrea still i have one question for you above code enabling particular date will work only for current year.Acturally I need the functionality enabling particular dates for two years like this==> availableDates = ["8-12-2014","25-12-2014","26-12-2014","25-01-2015","16-01-2015"]; how to solve this? and one more thing yeah now i upgraded to struts2.2.3 and struts2-jquery 3.7.1

Comment: You should migrate to **2.3.16.3**, really... the biggest security fix is on 2.3.**15**.3, but other fixes have been added since then. About your question in comment: if replace the array in the answer with your in the comment, it should work. Have you tried, do you have any problem ? Remember to always try before asking ;)

Comment: Yeah andrea i have already tried before posting my above comment only with this array==> availableDates = ["8-12-2014","25-12-2014","26-12-2014","25-01-2015","16-01-2015"]; but not enabling on 2015th year january month dates and january month dates everything is disabled on calendar. I think need to modify this line==>var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" 
                + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" 
                + date.getFullYear(); because ur using date.getFullYear() method that's why its reflecting only to current years dates

Comment: Aaahn, no, found it. You are doing String comparison, then you must ensure the string is the same. Remove the 0 in front of your dates (both days and months), because the Date's methods won't return them to you. Then you will compare `25-1-2015` to `25-01-2015`